# Hide more and print button in openerp

Tags: menu, hide, odoo

I want to disable a menu from "More" options in form view Product but i don't know where to find this form  and also how to do it .

Please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way to hide print and more button in all openerp interfaces. Go to :

```
openerpDir\addons\web\static\src\css\base.css
```

Replace:

```
.openerp .oe_sidebar {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

With:

```
.openerp .oe_sidebar {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's work also but i prefer Akhil P Sivan answer

Answer (score 2):

You can goto **Settings >> Technical >> Action >> Action Bindings**. Then in search Group By **Model** and **Type**. Find the model **product.product** and expand it. You can see two types, **client_print_multi** (for items under Print button)and **client_action_relate** (for items under More button). You can choose the one you want and delete those entries which you want to hide in that type.

These action bindings are stored in "ir_values" table in your database.

Comment: HI Akhil, If i need to hide more menu based on particular group or something do you have idea how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which menu you want to hide, find object of that menu and set access right for that object from:-

**Settings ==> Groups --> access rights** tab